# Не работают команды после одной функции

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, sqlite3

Не работают команды если этот код вставить в начало, но зато пользователь новый создается если его нет в БД:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def mess_handler(message: types.Message):
    if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
```

Если вставить это в конец, а не в начало работать не будет данный код:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def mess_handler(message: types.Message):
    if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
```

Comment: Заранее спасибо всем 

Comment: Ну наверное потому-что этот хендлер впитывает в себя все хендлеры типа текст и с нулевим стейтом? Если вы поставите его в конец кода то все будет ок.